# pip installing gsutil causes too many incompatible dependencies

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gsutil

When I run `pip install -U pip`, I get the following error:

```
proto-google-cloud-spanner-v1 0.15.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.1.2 which is incompatible.
proto-google-cloud-spanner-admin-instance-v1 0.15.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.1.2 which is incompatible.
proto-google-cloud-spanner-admin-database-v1 0.15.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.1.2 which is incompatible.
proto-google-cloud-pubsub-v1 0.15.4 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.1.2 which is incompatible.
proto-google-cloud-logging-v2 0.91.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.1.2 which is incompatible.
proto-google-cloud-error-reporting-v1beta1 0.15.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.1.2 which is incompatible.
proto-google-cloud-datastore-v1 0.90.4 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.1.2 which is incompatible.
gapic-google-cloud-spanner-v1 0.15.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.1.2 which is incompatible.
gapic-google-cloud-spanner-admin-instance-v1 0.15.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.1.2 which is incompatible.
gapic-google-cloud-spanner-admin-database-v1 0.15.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.1.2 which is incompatible.
gapic-google-cloud-pubsub-v1 0.15.4 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.1.2 which is incompatible.
gapic-google-cloud-logging-v2 0.91.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.1.2 which is incompatible.
gapic-google-cloud-error-reporting-v1beta1 0.15.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.1.2 which is incompatible.
gapic-google-cloud-datastore-v1 0.15.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.1.2 which is incompatible.
```

This is apparently because I have used `pip install gsutil` which according to [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install#linux) is experimental. I've been trying to uninstall it and other packages and also tried downgrading `oauth2client` which is also apparently deprecated, but I end up with too many other incompatible dependencies. Is there any quick fix to this?

Comment: Where did you try to install it (locally, a GCE VM...)? Is it supposed to be a warning or an actual error? As you can see, you have a newer version of oauth2client, so  maybe whatever you want to do works fine. Either way, have you tried to force install oauth2client 4.0.0? If not, try this: `sudo pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall oauth2client==4.0`. In any case, I would follow @the0ther recommendation.

Comment: I'm installing it in the base conda environment. This is a warning but leads to errors when I use Pipelines API. Downgrading oauth2client to 4.0 isn't sufficient to meet the compatibility. When I downgrade to 3, I still have the following: `gsutil 4.33 has requirement oauth2client==4.1.2, but you'll have oauth2client 3.0.0 which is incompatible.`. Let me try @the0ther recommendation and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing quite as good as installing the Google CloudSDK if you want to use `gsutil`. Is there any reason to not go that route?

If you are looking to clean up from a bad `pip install` of gsutil, then you're going to want to

1. Fully purge the pip installed package
2. Install Cloud SDK

Then basic Linux software installation things, like looking at your `PATH` to make sure `gsutil` and `gcloud` are "on the path". Use `which gsutil` if things seem murky.

Comment: Thanks. I had installed Google CloudSDK, but had a conda version, and a `/usr/lib` version of google cloud, and the PATH was pointing to them first. Doing `rm -rf miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/*google*` and similar thing with root, then install/uninstall with `gcloud componenet install gsutil` solved the problem. 
These pip installs seem to be automatic installations done by some in-house python package at my company.